# VSCode & Ionide: Unable to trigger breakpoint

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, ionide

I am unable to get *debugging* to work on a .NetCore solution using *Visual Studio Code* with the *Ionide* plugin.

Specifically, the breakpoint that I set is not getting triggered.

[image]

My *Launch.json* is the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/Nikeza.Server.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "externalTerminal" //"internalConsole"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/Nikeza.Server.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the DLL that I'm referencing in my bin folder:

[image]

Here's the [GitHub solution](https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza/tree/master/Server).

I have referenced the following links:

- [.NET Core Debugging in VS Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/10/experimental-net-core-debugging-in-vs-code/)
- [Setting Up Visual Studio Code Debugging for .NET Core Projects](https://medium.com/@mikezrimsek/setting-up-visual-studio-code-debugging-for-net-core-projects-af18424ae3f)

Comment: Sadly Iodine does not currently support debugging on windows systems. See http://ionide.io/. The section on Debugging says that it only works on Linux and OS X.